# Getting auto update working with greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have forked a greasemonkey script and want it to auto update on version change like the original and have edited the

> @updateURL
>   and
>   @downloadURL

options to point to the correct files but for whatever reason the script will not update when i push an updated build with an incremented version number.

my meta.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         4chan X with translator
// @version      1.13.6.1
// @minGMVer     1.14
// @minFFVer     26
// @namespace    4chan-X
// @description  Cross-browser userscript for maximum lurking on 4chan.
// @license      MIT; https://github.com/ccd0/4chan-x/blob/master/LICENSE 
// @include      http://boards.4chan.org/*
// @include      https://boards.4chan.org/*
// @include      http://sys.4chan.org/*
// @include      https://sys.4chan.org/*
// @include      http://www.4chan.org/*
// @include      https://www.4chan.org/*
// @include      http://i.4cdn.org/*
// @include      https://i.4cdn.org/*
// @include      http://is.4chan.org/*
// @include      https://is.4chan.org/*
// @include      http://is2.4chan.org/*
// @include      https://is2.4chan.org/*
// @include      https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6Ldp2bsSAAAAAAJ5uyx_lx34lJeEpTLVkP5k04qc*
// @include      https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/frame?*&k=6Ldp2bsSAAAAAAJ5uyx_lx34lJeEpTLVkP5k04qc*
// @include      https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/frame?*&k=887877714&*
// @include      http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6Ldp2bsSAAAAAAJ5uyx_lx34lJeEpTLVkP5k04qc*
// @include      https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6Ldp2bsSAAAAAAJ5uyx_lx34lJeEpTLVkP5k04qc*
// @exclude      http://www.4chan.org/pass
// @exclude      https://www.4chan.org/pass
// @exclude      http://www.4chan.org/pass?*
// @exclude      https://www.4chan.org/pass?*
// @exclude      http://www.4chan.org/advertise
// @exclude      https://www.4chan.org/advertise
// @exclude      http://www.4chan.org/advertise?*
// @exclude      https://www.4chan.org/advertise?*
// @exclude      http://www.4chan.org/donate
// @exclude      https://www.4chan.org/donate
// @exclude      http://www.4chan.org/donate?*
// @exclude      https://www.4chan.org/donate?*
// @connect      4chan.org
// @connect      4cdn.org
// @connect      *
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_deleteValue
// @grant        GM_listValues
// @grant        GM_addValueChangeListener
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at       document-start
// @updateURL    https://translate.ss13.moe/4chan-X.meta.js
// @downloadURL  https://translate.ss13.moe/4chan-X.user.js
// @icon         data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAMAAABg3Am1AAAACVBMVEUAAGcAAABmzDNZt9VtAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAF5JREFUeNrtkTESABAQxPD/R6tsE2dUGYUtFJvLDKf93KevHJAjpBorAQWSBIKqFASC4G0pCAkm4GfaEvgYXl0T6HBaE97f0vmnfYHbZOMLZCx9ISdKWwjOWZSC8GYm4SUGwfYgqI4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
// ==/UserScript==
```

Comment: You have this tagged as Greasemonkey but `GM_addValueChangeListener` is not valid Greasemonkey (only Tampermonkey). Are you using Firefox, Chrome, or what?

Comment: I personally use Firefox but the script is cross platform.

Comment: The script is NOT cross platform if it uses GM_addValueChangeListener.  That works only on Chrome+Tampermonkey.  GM and TM handle updates slightly differently as well.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you I didn't make the entirety of the script originally but it works on firefox and greasemonkey as that's what I use, but I've just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Two update attributes, i.e. `@updateURL` and `@downloadURL`, are not supported in GreaseMonkey 4.0+ which is around the time when this question was posted. If you are facing the same problem just use [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) instead.

Comment: OP is asking about GreaseMonkey; not TamperMonkey

Comment: @Zoe just take a minute and read what I've written. It's saying that current version of GM doesn't support these meta attributes.

Comment: I did read it, and the part I'm specifically talking about is the last line.

Comment: Which is a suggestion that if OP wants to keep on using these attributes then TM is an option.